# Why does host's antivirus detect guest's malware?

Tags: malware, virtualization, antimalware

I'm analyzing some malicious files on a VM and I'm noticing that every time I open a file, the host's antivirus detects it.

Why does this happen? Is the malicious content escaping to the host?

Comment: out of curiosity, what VM technology are you using?

Comment: I'm using VirtualBox

Answer (score 3):

What I'd guess is happening is: When the guest OS reads an infected file, the hypervisor reads part for of the virtual disk file, the host anti-virus intercepts this read, scans it for viruses, and detects the virus in the guest.

As a workaround I would configure your host AV to ignore the virtual disk files.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the host and the VM are not isolated.

Maybe, there is a network connection whenever you open this file. Moreover, the antivirus may have detected a threat if there are shared folders between the VM and the host.

I would check the network configuration and the shared files.

Comment: No shared files, guest's network adapter is configured as NAT.

Comment: Ok, what software do you use for virtualization?